# Using volatile keyword for creating one instance

Tags: java, concurrency, osgi

I have the following code:

```
public class EntityManagerFactoryProviderImpl implements EntityManagerFactoryProvider {

  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory=null;//line XXX

  public EntityManagerFactory getFactory(){
      if (entityManagerFactory==null){
          buildFactory();
      }
      return entityManagerFactory;
  }

  private synchronized void buildFactory(){
      if (entityManagerFactory!=null){
          return;
      }
      entityManagerFactory=...
  }
}
```

So I need that `entityManagerFactory` instance was created only once - when `getFactory()` is first called.

Must I set variable `entityManagerFactory` on line XXX as volatile this case?

Also, `EntityManagerFactoryProviderImpl` is an OSGI Singleton Declarative Service, so there is always only one instance of this class.

Comment: Glad you found my answer and that link helpful. Thanks for the timely accept!

Comment: @GhostCat I also thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are theoretical possibilities that multiple threads are calling the code in parallel; and due to *not* using volatile, thread A doesn't see updates that thread B made.I have never encountered such behavior myself, but surr: it is possible and when it happens, very strange bugs might come out of having two instances of the same singleton.

You can study this [SEI cert site](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MSC07-J.+Prevent+multiple+instantiations+of+singleton+objects) for a full discussion of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see why you need to make this volatile. You use the double checked locking solution in your example. The [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MSC07-J.+Prevent+multiple+instantiations+of+singleton+objects) in the accepted answer also indicates this is compliant.

So the accepted answer is actually wrong, you do not need volatile. Howeer, the cleanest solution for this  kind of initialization is the "initialize-on-Demand Holder Class Idiom" which is also at the [link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MSC07-J.+Prevent+multiple+instantiations+of+singleton+objects).

*Update* I was wrong. The double check locking can fail because the EntityManagerFactory object can be seen in a partially constructed state, only final fields in this objects are guaranteed to be seen. This is explicitly mentioned in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5-110

```
  int j = f.y;  // could see 0
```

The "initialize-on-Demand Holder Class Idiom" is fastest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand, at the provided link Noncompliant are bad solutions, and Compliant are good solution (I am not native speaker of English)

Comment: Please, note, that I am speaking about Compliant Solution (Double-Checked Locking).

Comment: No, this is incorrect. If you don't use volatile here, then it's possible for some thread to observe not fully constructed object. It won't be null, but some fields will be null in that case. You can read about it here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html (section "So what's broken about DCL?")

Comment: @Pavel volatile is needed here only to solve this problem with unproperly constructed object.  Volatile DOES not solve the problem with visibility. Even if you have volatile field it's not guaranteed by JMM that it will be visible right after the write to the field. Actually, in you code snippet it's not possible to create object twice simply due to happens-before semantics. So volatile is only needed to publish object properly

Answer (score 0):

The code in question isn't threadsafe because it has a check then act problem in the public method. The reason for this problem is that shared mutable state isn't properly syncrhonized in the class. Here's a solution:

```
public class EntityManagerFactory implements ....{

private static class EntityManagerHolder {
  public static EntityManager entityManager = new EntityManager();
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
  return EntityManagerHolder.entityManager;
}

}
```

Notice that there's no synchronized keyword here. This is because entityManager is initialized as static in the holder class which means it's loaded after class loading but before any threads can start and hence no synchrnonization is needed.

The sole purpose of the holder class is to prevent an eager initialization cost by using the JVM lazy class loading strategy. The holder class is only initialized when it's actually needed rather than at class load time with an eager static initialization.

Bottomline: You avoid synchronized and eager initialization and get a singleton all in one fell swoop. ;)